# Transform Parallels Windows disk in native Windows, bootable with Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, parallels-desktop

I use Parallels 8 to run Windows 7 in my MacBook with Mountain Lion. But I'd like to have  Windows running natively in my Mac. I don't want to start again with a clean Windows installation, and configure all the software I need from scratch. So, I had this crazy idea...

Is there any way I can *transform* my Parallels Virtual Disk containing Windows 7 in a native partition bootable via Bootcamp? I assume it's just too complicated, or even impossible. But need to be sure.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I found [an old thread on the Parallels support forums](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?6433-Virtual-to-Physical-%28Boot-Camp%29-Guide) which has instructions to do that, but it doesn't look easy. People have asked if it's still relevant today but there hasn't been an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I finally created a new fresh partition and install Windows 7 from scratch. Not as long as I thought. But I keep the link, for future references.